# MIPS floating point add example

Tags: floating-point, mips

I am trying to write a MIPS program that will add two floating point integers togerther, the first floating point integer is the two's complement of -8.0

the second is the floating pointinteger 2.0

so first I changed -8 to two's compliment which is 1000 then I converted that to hex so my hex would be 0x00000008

my MIPS program so far looks like this

```
l.s $f1, 0x00000008
l.s $f2, 15.0
add.s $f0, $f1, $f2
```

I get an error on this obviously any help?

Also I am confused when loading in floating integers in the commant l.s $f2, 15.0 I know this is not right. how can I load 15 into the registry as a floating point? and again my ultimate question how can I add the two together using MIPS. thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To start with, the floating point number 8 is not represented as 0x00000008.  Remember that floating point numbers are represented using the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) standard.

If you want to add 0x8 and 0xF, then you should:

1. Load each of them into a fp register (using `l.s`)
2. Use the `cvt.s.w` instruction (convert single from word) to convert them into floating point registers.
3. add